# MongoDB Driver C# trying to do basic math but don't understand aggregation

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, bson

I have a collection of BsonDocuments that each have a field named "engagement" (which is a number) and also a field named "color". I would like total sum of cost for all BsonDocuments where "color" = "blue".

So far from what I've found is I need to do something like this:

```
            var collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("collectionName");

            var match = new BsonDocument
            {
                {
                    "$match",
                    new BsonDocument
                        {
                            {"sentiment", "positive"}
                        }
                }
            };

            var group = new BsonDocument
            {
                { "$group",
                    new BsonDocument
                        {
                            {
                                "Sum", new BsonDocument
                                             {
                                                 {
                                                     "$sum", "$engagement"
                                                 }
                                             }
                            }
                        }
              }
            };

            var pipeline = new[] { match, group };
            var result = collection.Aggregate(pipeline);
```

I've been getting an error about the type methods arguments for the Aggregate method cannot be inferred from the usage.

Simply put, I would like to know how to perform simple math operations with the the Aggregate Framework. In this example, I am trying to sum all the values of the engagement field from all of the BsonDocuments in my collection. The utilization of Builder functions would be great if possible but the manually created BsonDocument will serve just as well.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

When you use [$group](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/), you need to tell the aggregation framework *by which fields* you want to group. You do that in the `_id` field to the group-object. Also, if you want a simple document count, you need to use `{ $sum : 1 }` to count one per document. If you use a field-name, you tell the aggregation to interpret the values of that field as numbers and add them up.

In MongoDB shell syntax:

```
{ $group: {
     _id: "$engagement",
     Sum: { $sum: 1 }
}}
```

Translated to C# (untested!):

```
{ "$group", new BsonDocument 
    { 
        { "_id", "$engagement" }, 
        { "Sum", new BsonDocument 
            { 
                { 
                    "$sum", 1 
                } 
             } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I understand the aggregate better now.

I'm still getting the error about the type methods arguments for the Aggregate method cannot be inferred from the usage in the line of code where I declared the result. Have any idea what this could be about?